# opencart subcategory description on category

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to add description on subcategories (refine search) and I fail. What I do is to add the following line in "product/category.tpl"
but the text that is shown is from the parent category. Can anybody help me? 2.3.0.2

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do?

Comment: How to Add descripton Subcategory in Category Page ?

Answer (score 0):

open file: catalog/controller/product/category.php

```
$data['categories'][] = array(
    'name' => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url),
    'thumb' => $image
            );
```

add `'sub_desc' => utf8_substr(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), 0)` after `'thumb' => $image` don't forget the ","

```
$data['categories'][] = array(
    'name' => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url),
    'thumb' => $image,
    'sub_desc' => utf8_substr(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), 0)
            );
```

then in: catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl

```
<?php if (!empty($category['sub_desc']))  { ?>
    <div class="description"><?php echo $category['sub_desc']; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

and you will get subcategory descripton of each subcategory:)